# jquery ceases to work inside a reloaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using something like this `$('#msgs').load("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> #msgs");` to reload a div which contains [a table that allows for dynamic sorting by the user](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

The problem I am facing is, not just the table run by tablesorter, but any other time I reload a div this way, any jquery functions that would normally operate in the div no longer function. Is there any way around this with out pushing the data?

```
$(function () {
    $("#backups") 
        .tablesorter({
            widgets: ['zebra'],
            sortList: [
                [1, 1],
                [2, 1],
            ],
            headers: {
                6: {
                    sorter: false
                },
            }
    })
    .tablesorterPager({
        container: $("#pager")
    });
    $('#create').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '?process=create',
            data: '',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#backups')
                        .load("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> #backups");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

For example if I click the event `#create`, the div `#backups` reloads under which circumstances the tablesorter code for backups ceases to work.

UPDATE:
I created a fiddle that shows the issue. If you click the button, then the sorting abilities of the table no longer works. I'm a learn by example type person, and I'm not sure what to do with the below answers. Could someone perhaps show me using my fiddle how to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/1mfgfd2n/7/show/

Comment: rerun the jQuery that sets up the table stuff. In the finish callback `$("#myTable").tablesorter(); `

Comment: You need to use delegated events rather than direct events. E.g. `click()` is a great example of a direct event. If you load a div with AJAX that has a hyperlink you want to target in it, click won't handle that event (because it didn't know about it when you assigned it). Use `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){})` to use a delegated event that WILL apply to newly created elements. There's **lots** of this documented in Stack Overflow, have a search for it.

Comment: If you talking about events, then you might have to go for live events. Please check `on()` in jQuery once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept behind live events in jQuery is simple. Lets say you have HTML,

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Now through AJAX or whatever means you prefer, you load a button inside this div.

```
$.get("url", function(data) {
    $('.container').html('<button class="submit-something">Submit</button>');
});
```

If you have added the event handler on `$(document).ready`,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit-something').click(clickHandler);
});
```

But when the document is ready, there is no button. This applies for any of the 'jQuery stuff' you want to do with the updated content. Unless, you have the element you are accessing via selector exists, jQuery can't do anything.

A possible generic solution (for events, there's `live` or `on`) is to add the 'jQuery stuff' inside the AJAX callback.

```
$.get("url", function(data) {
    $('.container').html('<button class="submit-something">Submit</button>');
    $('.submit-something').click(clickHandler);
});
```

You can always check at any point of time, whether the element exists  or not by simply adding a console log.

```
console.log($('.submit-something').length);
```

Hope this answers your question regarding any jQuery operation you want to perform.

UPDATE:

`load` event is a special case that cannot be tested in this way. However, it is intuitive that the content inside the element where I called load event is cleared. So any event or tablesorter associated with it, no longer applies. Once the content is loaded, you need to associate the event or tablesorter again to the inner elements. This is same as getting a response from AJAX and rebinding the event.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tejasj/1mfgfd2n/11/. When you reload, the table `#backup` was recreated. So tablesorter is not associated with the new `#backup` table.

Comment: Huh i thought that may be the case but i figured there would be some built in functionality to automagically do this. is that the only way to do it?

Comment: If you are destroying the table and recreating it, Yes. You can actually load only the content inside table. That way, any event associated with it, is retained. Not sure about tablesorter though. Haven't used it before. I prefer re-inventing the wheel when it comes to such plugins.

Comment: Yea reloading the content inside would be a tedious endeavor, ill stick with your suggestion and rebuild the function! Thanks for your answer and your help!